# Do 'multi-level' sets arise outside of set theory? And is it critical that we allow the construction of such collections?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

In real analysis, subsets of $\mathcal{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ arise a lot, for many different choices of $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, I've never seen a 'multi-level' set, like I've never seen a subset of $\mathbb{R} \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ that can be expressed in the form $A \cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty sets satisfying $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $B \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}).$

Along a similar vein, I have never seen anything like $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{P}^n(\mathbb{R}).$ Are there situations where these kinds of 'multi-level' collections arise naturally, outside of set-theory? I'm not insisting the base case be $\mathbb{R}$ - that was just an example.

Anyway, here's a related question. Is it critical for the rest of mathematics (outside of set theory) that we allow the construction of such collections?

Comment: Well, if $\Bbb R$ is really just $\mathcal P(\omega)$ then $\mathcal P^n(\Bbb R)\subseteq\mathcal P^m(\Bbb R)$ whenever $n\leq m$... :-)

Comment: Also, I don't recall seeing any set which was explicitly of cardinality larger than that of $\Bbb R$ during my undergrad (sans the advanced set theory course, and a reading course about cardinal arithmetics), let alone $\mathcal P^n(\Bbb R)$ for $n>1$. Where do they arise?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the source of the partial function $\sup : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Ehhhhh... I agree it counts, but I don't think it really counts. It's not even critical for real analysis. You can define it in second-order logic over $\Bbb R$ (or as a schema in first-order, but only for a small part of the sets of course). I wouldn't consider this a valid example. Sure, it's one of these formal technicalities which are correct (yes, the $\sup$ function is a large set), but it isn't really a good example in my eyes.

Comment: IF one learns measure theory in undergrad, then the set of measurable sets and the set of null sets would be an example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I will let you know if I can think of a better example.

Comment: @BabyDragon, the Lebesgue measurable sets as well the $\sup$ function are both of cardinality $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$. These are practically the only two examples one sees, but those are not treated as sets per se, it would be perfectly fine for measure theorists if $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ was a class, as long as we can do things to it; and similarly for the $\sup$. In either case, my comment said that $n>1$, and both the examples are for $n=1$. I suppose that I should have said "rarely" rather than "I don't recall".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, how about this one. A partitioning of a connected set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ into intervals, in order to define intergration. Every such partitioning is an element of $\mathcal{P}^2(\mathbb{R}),$ and the set of all such partitionings of $X$ is an element of $\mathcal{P}^3(\mathbb{R}).$ Even if you replace the word 'element' with the word 'subset' and drop all the exponents by 1, we still got to 2.

Comment: @user18921: No go. These are finite partitions, determined uniquely by the endpoints of the intervals. So these are finite sequences of real numbers. It is true that we can talk about the singleton $\{\{\ldots\{\Bbb R\}\ldots\}\}$, it is a subset of some $\mathcal P^n(\Bbb R)$, but this misses the point, and we don't really care about all that set. Similarly here, there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ such partitions anyway, and $2^{\aleph_0}$ intervals, so there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ relevant objects anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, okay point taken. I have edited the question to emphasize that its not large cardinalities per se that I'm asking about, but rather, collections whose elements come from different 'levels'.

Answer (score 2):

In geometry, one often thinks of a line (or circle or ...) as a set of points, but one also wants to consider a configuration as a set of points and lines.  So a configuration is a two-level set.

If one represents functions as sets of ordered pairs and represents ordered pairs as sets in the usual way, then any function from elements of a set $X$ to subsets of $X$ (or vice versa) will involve (inside the ordered pairs) two-level sets.  More levels arise in the case of functions that move things up or down by more than one step in the set-theoretic hierarchy, for example the function that sends a point in $\mathbb R$ to the Dirac measure concentrated at that point.

Comment: I liked the geometry example. +1

Comment: Yeah, but if you exclude tuples and functions (which are “multi-leveled” only technically, really), do you have any interesting examples? Ignoring situations where “levels” do not make much sense, like with ordinal numbers...

Comment: @tomasz, the first sentence of this answer gives an interesting example.

Comment: @user18921: I think this is a little more complex: we clearly tell lines and points apart.

Comment: @tomasz, if you're saying that a configuration is better viewed as a subset of the tagged union $\mathbb{R}^2 \sqcup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2),$ as opposed to a subset of the 'straight' union $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2),$ then I tend to agree. If not, what are you saying?

Comment: Pretty much. That, or actually a pair: a subset of the plane, and a set of subsets of the plane. Then again, this is the same thing as you said, at the abstract level.

Comment: @tomasz, yes I agree with what you're saying.